# Does Liquibase have a similar option to Flyway's clean-on-validation-error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, flyway

Due to version issues we switched from Flyway to Liquibase in a Spring Boot 3 environment.

As we are still in an non production-environment our database-schema is rapidly changing and we don't care about data loss.
However, as we are changing the schema we don't want to introduce new scripts but rather change the initial script as long as we are not productive.

While using Flyway we would use the option `clean-on-validation-error` to only drop the existing database when changes in the schema have to be applied.

With Liquibase we only found the option `drop-first`, which leads to resetting the database on every restart of the application, even without a new version deployment but rather having Kubernetes restart a pod.

When I say "we don't care about data loss" I speak about those data produced while testing the application. There are a lot of "core-data" which have to be generated by batch-jobs when the database is emptied.

My question:

Is there a way simulating Flyway's `clean-on-validation-error`'s behaviour using Spring Boot 3 and Liquibase?

What we have done:
read the docs at https://docs.liquibase.com, tried multiple liquibase properties.

Comment: What were the version issues with flyway?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and elaborate on what properties did you try?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with Liquibase closely, but here are some thoughts on this.

I believe that the use case you describe is not very common because the code tends to be updated and deployed frequently and in *any* environment tier higher than a local container a change in an existing changeset may (and most likely *will*) cause problems and time loss for the team. Making the changesets atomic, reversible and immutable is a best practice for Liquibase. Otherwise you can spend time on performing manual rollbacks, applying fixes to the [changeset checksums](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changeset-checksums.html), and running redeployments.

But you still have options (some of them are worth to do anyways):

- run [`validate`](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/update/validate.html) command before `update` (BTW I highly recommend using [`update-testing-rollback`](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/update/update-testing-rollback.html) instead), add apply `dropFirst` parameter only in case of validation failure;
- define different [contexts](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/contexts.html) for different environments and/or changeset categories, split the executions by contexts, and apply `dropFirst` only to contexts that are deployed to certain environments or fall into "we don`t care about data loss" category;
- see if other [attributes](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/home.html) (possibly along with [preconditions](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/preconditions.html)) such as [onValidationFail](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/on-validation-fail.html), [failOnError](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/fail-on-error.html), [ignore](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/ignore.html), [runAlways](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/run-always.html), or [runOnChange](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/runonchange.html) could help
- if you use Liquibase Pro, chances are that [flows](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/flow/flow.html) can help you implement exactly the logic you expect;
- also, Liquibase Pro has [rollback-on-error](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/update/update.html#command) attribute;
- finally, you can implement your own [extension](https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/extensions-overview/).

Liquibase is very flexible but I doubt it's possible to do what you want with only one parameter. I may have missed something, though.